# Rspec/Rails controller testing 404 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is my test:

```
  describe "GET show" do

    it "assigns service_request as @service_request" do
      get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: service_request.id }
      expect(assigns(:service_request)).to eq service_request
    end

    it "returns 404 when service_request is not found" do
      get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: "foo" }
      expect(response.status).to eq 404
    end

  end
```

The error in my terminal is:

```
  1) ServiceRequestsController GET show returns 404 when service_request is not found
     Failure/Error: get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: "foo" }
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find ServiceRequest with 'id'=foo [WHERE (company_id IS NOT NULL)]
     # ./spec/controllers/service_requests_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Obviously this isn't correct, but I'm not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails is throwing an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error instead of redirecting to a general 404 page. You need to handle that error with a rescue_from in the controller and redirect to a 404 view with status 404.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it would return a status 404 if this was a `request` spec right? Since its a controller level spec, it won't go down the whole stack to the exceptions app.

Comment: @LeoCorrea That may be the case but I'm not 100% sure. But I do know what's causing the error for him because I had the same problem not very long ago.

Comment: Request specs will also pass through RecordNotFound by default, due to the consider_all_requests_local setting explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware

Answer (score 4):

Just had this issue. It turns out that in the test environment, rails shows error messages to help with debugging.

[This blog post](https://eliotsykes.com/2017/03/08/realistic-error-responses/) details a way of getting "production-like" error responses to test your API responses. It recommends creating a helper `spec/support/error_responses.rb`:

```
module ErrorResponses

  def respond_without_detailed_exceptions
    env_config = Rails.application.env_config
    original_show_exceptions = env_config["action_dispatch.show_exceptions"]
    original_show_detailed_exceptions = env_config["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"]
    env_config["action_dispatch.show_exceptions"] = true
    env_config["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] = false
    yield
  ensure
    env_config["action_dispatch.show_exceptions"] = original_show_exceptions
    env_config["action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"] = original_show_detailed_exceptions
  end

end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ErrorResponses

  config.around(realistic_error_responses: true) do |example|
    respond_without_detailed_exceptions(&example)
  end
end
```

This can then be used in your case as follows. Note the use of `:realistic_error_responses`.

```
describe "GET show", :realistic_error_responses do
  it "assigns service_request as @service_request" do
    get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: service_request.id }
    expect(assigns(:service_request)).to eq service_request
  end

  it "returns 404 when service_request is not found" do
    get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: "foo" }
    expect(response.status).to eq 404
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

A nicer way to write this is like so.

```
it "returns 404 when service_request is not found" do
  get :show, { company_id: @company.id, id: "foo" }
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
end
```

And you can find other Rails HTTP Status symbols [here](https://httpstatuses.com/404).

Comment: However, this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: LMAO my bad! :D